# When is the latest i can apply for Uk visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

It only says in the web the earliest you can apply which is 3 months before travel. How about the latest time i can apply? Would they grant me a Sept 2019 visa if I applied on July 2019???

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, as the answer depends on how long it takes UKVI to review your application and act on it, and that in turn depends on what office or consulate does the work, and how busy they are, and on who-knows-what other factors. UKVI maintains a webpage that lists typical processing times and various UKVI locations, but these are _typical_ times, not promised times. Some applications take longer.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out typical processing times for visa applications [here](https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times). Fifteen days is typical for many centres, but you should check your nearest.

Allow extra time for unexpected delays, and work back from your intended travel date.

For best peace of mind you should apply as early as possible, but no more than three months ahead of time. For a 1st September travel date you should apply now.